# C Pointer manipulation

Tags: c, pointers, stack

I'm doing the famous "smash  the stack" tutorial and I got stuck. Basically I manipulate a pointer to point to the return address at the stack. And then manipulate the return address itself. So my goal is to over jump the instruction x = 1;

Please check my code, in my opionen it should work. I even turned off ASLR... but no effect

But at the end I still prints "1"... Can't tell why :-(

Code from tutorial:

```
void function(int a, int b, int c) {
   char buffer1[5];
   char buffer2[10];
   int *ret;

   ret = buffer1 + 12;
   (*ret) += 8;
}

void main() {
  int x;

  x = 0;
  function(1,2,3);
  x = 1;
  printf("%d\n",x);
}
```

My Code (first try):

```
void function(int a, int b, int c) {

   // Dont really know if initiated arrays have a different address than non initiated...
   char buffer1[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
   char buffer2[10];
   int *ret;

   ret = buffer1;

   int i;
   for(i=0;i<64;i++){
   printf("Added: %d, Address: %016x\n",i,(*ret));
   ret += i;
   //Found out that adding 5 points to the return address on the stack
   if(i == 5) break;

   }

   printf("stack address of ret: %p\n", ret);
   printf("unchanged ret address: %016x\n", (*ret));

   //Just counted the bytes to pass the x = 1; movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
   (*ret) += 7;
   printf("changed ret address: %016x\n", (*ret));
}

void main() {
  int x;

  x = 0;
  function(1,2,3);
  x = 1;
  printf("print x: %d\n",x);
}
```

**Update**:
My code is working now (it skips x = 1). I'll post that code if anybody is interested ...

Greetz!

Comment: it will of course print 1 only

Comment: so where is my mistake?

Comment: and compile with -fno-stack-protector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void function(int a, int b, int c) {
char buffer1[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
char buffer2[10];
char *ret;

ret = buffer1;

ret += 0x18;

printf("stack address of ret: %p\n", ret);
printf("unchanged ret address: 0x%x%02x%x\n",ret[2],ret[1],ret[0]);
printf("unchanged ret address: %p\n", *(void **)ret);
printf("unchanged ret address: 0x%06x\n", *(unsigned int *)ret &      0x00FFFFFF);
printf("unchanged ret address: 0x%03x\n", *(unsigned int *)ret );

//Just counted the bytes to pass the x = 1; movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp) 
(*ret) += 7;
//printf("changed ret address: %p\n",(*ret));
printf("changed ret address: 0x%03x\n", *(unsigned int *)ret );
}

void main() {
int x;

x = 0;
function(1,2,3);
x = 1;
printf("print x: %d\n",x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a number of problems - I don't think you understand what you are trying to do.
Step back and ask yourself what does the stack look like?

Assuming 64 bit CPU, your pointers are 8 bytes (64 bits) and your ints, lets assume are 4 bytes (32 bits) each, then you have 5 chars one byte each plus another 10 chars, plus another pointer (8 bytes), plus the variable i.
So your stack looks like this:

```
<return address>        <8 bytes>
<function parameters>   <12 bytes>
<buffer1>               <5 bytes>   
<buffer2>               <10 bytes>
<ret>                   <8 bytes>
<i>
```

Your pointer is pointing to buffer1, to get the return address you need to backup 20 bytes and read 8.
Since your are doing this to learn, I won't give you the answer but here is a hint:

```
//Chars are 1 byte, ints are 4, char != int
char buffer1[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
char* currentAddress = &buffer1;

printf("Value: %c, Address: %016x\n",(*currentAddress), currentAddress);

//move 1 byte forward
currentAddress++;

//print a char
printf("Value: %c, Address: %016x\n",(*currentAddress), currentAddress);

//move back
currentAddress--;

//print a char
printf("Value: %c, Address: %016x\n",(*currentAddress), currentAddress);    

//back up one int - safer than just saying back up 4 bytes
currentAddress -= sizeof(int);
//Print an int, notice the cast.
printf("Value: %d, Address: %016x\n",(*(int*)currentAddress), currentAddress);
```

Comment: well, i got it work. your explanation has several errors. stack looks different than you showed (its not function parameters its EBP). And local variables really has word sizes...